# ActiveMQ - Unable to read from just one (out of many) topics

Tags: activemq-classic

I wonder if any one has run into this issue. I am using C# 6, .Net Fx 4.6 with Apache NMS library 1.7.2 to connect to a production server. I can connect to any topic on the server. I can read read messages from all topics except one using the same code. This is making me think if the issue was with my code I wouldn't have been able to read from any topic. (The only difference is that the topic I can't read from has a much higher volume of messages arriving than the other topics that I can read from.) I have tried this using both polling and setting up a callback listener with same results.

This is how I am polling:

var objMessages = Consumer.ReceiveNoWait();

Has anyone ever run into a situation where they can read from one topic on the server but not from another? Much thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when reading that Topic?  Error etc?  Have you investigated this via web console etc?

Comment: This is an ActiveMQ installation on our premises by one of our vendors. The web console is either disabled or I do not have access to it. However, their technical resources confirm (using their monitoring tools) that we successfully connect to the topic in question. On our end NMS is not throwing any exceptions. I am using remote debugger and Consumer.ReceiveNoWait () keeps returning NULL even though there are messages in the topic.

Comment: not really enough to go on, receiveNoWait is not guaranteed to return a Message, use a timed receive instead to give more time.  Update your question with enough details for someone to really help (Code, Trace logs, debug info, etc)

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My application logs may or may not help. Are there any low level NMS logs I can capture to attach here? My company is happy to engage a consultant and pay him/her.